# Bad obtaining of the storage reference, impossible to solve

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, picasso, android-glide

Hello everyone I have a problem that I have tried to solve for 3 days without stopping, but I can not solve it and this is despairing, it is with the StorageReference,

When I call the `getReference()` method it gives me a "location must not be empty or null" but the point is if I am giving the storage reference, and when trying to use with `getReferenceFromUrl()`, run, you can get the photo with Glide or with picasso but to return to my activity I get a null pointer exception, that I can not use it. Is this

```
 "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getLastPathSegment ()' on a null object 
 reference"
```

The photos that I put in the method send arrive with success but when wanting to rescue them to use them in an IMageView with picasso or glide gives me that problem

I tried all the possible ways but it does not work

This is the class that gives me problems. The exception problem is in the populate viewHolder in the StorageRefence line and I put the file in the `sendComment` method

```
    private void initCommentSection() {
        RecyclerView commentRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.comment_recyclerview);
        commentRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(CommentActivity.this));
```

here in the populateVIewHolder is the problem, in the storage reference, in the getLastPathSegment()

```
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comment, CommentHolder> commentAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comment, CommentHolder>(
                        Comment.class,
                        R.layout.row_comment,
                        CommentHolder.class,
                        FirebaseUtils.getCommentRef(mPost.getPostId())) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder(final CommentHolder viewHolder, Comment model, int position) {
                        viewHolder.setUsername(mUser.getUsername());
                        viewHolder.setComment(model.getComment());
                        viewHolder.setTime(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(model.getTimeCreated()));



                        StorageReference sdsd = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(FirebaseUtils.getCommentsImagesRef().child(mSelectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment()).toString());
                        sdsd.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(CommentActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                             Picasso.with(CommentActivity.this).load(uri).into(viewHolder.imageBetaComm);
                            }
                        });

                        if(mSelectedImageUri == null){
                            StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/memetics-e9fac.appspot.com/o/bite_carpet%2Fbite.png?alt=media&token=36b90aed-5448-4493-836a-ad5554848820");
                            storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(CommentActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                 Picasso.with(CommentActivity.this).load(uri).into(viewHolder.imageBetaComm);
                                }
                            });
                        }








                    }
                };

        commentRecyclerView.setAdapter(commentAdapter);
    }
```

ans here sends the photo to the storage

```
    private void sendComment() {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CommentActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Sending comment..");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressDialog.show();

        final String uid = FirebaseUtils.getUid();
        final String strComment = mCommentEditTextView.getText().toString();




        FirebaseUtils.getUserRef(FirebaseUtils.getCurrentUser().getEmail().replace(".", ","))
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);


                        if(mSelectedImageUri != null){
                            mComent.setUser(user);
                            mComent.setCommentId(uid);
                            mComent.setComment(strComment);
                            mComent.setTimeCreated(System.currentTimeMillis());
                            FirebaseUtils.getCommentsImagesRef().child(mSelectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment()).putFile(mSelectedImageUri);
                        }else{
                            mComent.setUser(user);
                            mComent.setCommentId(uid);
                            mComent.setComment(strComment);
                            mComent.setTimeCreated(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        }



                        FirebaseUtils.getCommentRef(mPost.getPostId())
                                .child(uid)
                                .setValue(mComent);
                        FirebaseUtils.getMyCommentRef().child(uid).setValue(true);
                        FirebaseUtils.addToMyRecord(Constants.COMMENTS_KEY, uid);



                        FirebaseUtils.getPostRef().child(mPost.getPostId())
                                .child("numComments")
                                .runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                                        long num = (long) mutableData.getValue();
                                        mutableData.setValue(num + 1);
                                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        FirebaseUtils.addToMyRecord(Constants.COMMENTS_KEY,uid);
                                    }
                                });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: There's too much code here to help efficiently. Please post the [minimal code that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it's quite useful). Once you can reproduce the problem in a single method, with just hard-coded values, it'll be a lot easier to see what's going wrong.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  Now I just edited it and just put the neccesary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
if(mSelectedImageUri != null){
                        mComent.setUser(user);
                        mComent.setCommentId(uid);
                        mComent.setComment(strComment);
                        mComent.setTimeCreated(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        FirebaseUtils.getCommentsImagesRef().child(mSelectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment()).putFile(mSelectedImageUri).addOnSuccessListener(CommentActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                              String url = Constants.COMMENT_IMAGES + "/" + mSelectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment();
                                mComent.setPhotoCommentUrl(url);
                                FirebaseUtils.getCommentRef(mPost.getPostId())
                                        .child(uid)
                                        .setValue(mComent);
                                FirebaseUtils.getMyCommentRef().child(uid).setValue(true);
                                FirebaseUtils.addToMyRecord(Constants.COMMENTS_KEY, uid);



                            }
                        });
                    }else{
                        mComent.setUser(user);
                        mComent.setCommentId(uid);
                        mComent.setComment(strComment);
                        mComent.setTimeCreated(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        String urlnull = Constants.PHOTO_COMMENT_ROW + "/" + "bite.png";
                        mComent.setPhotoCommentUrl(urlnull);
                        FirebaseUtils.getCommentRef(mPost.getPostId())
                                .child(uid)
                                .setValue(mComent);
                        FirebaseUtils.getMyCommentRef().child(uid).setValue(true);
                        FirebaseUtils.addToMyRecord(Constants.COMMENTS_KEY, uid);

                    }
```